# Ionic 4: display image from camera plugin or where to find normalizeUrl

Tags: camera, ionic-native, ionic4

I want to format my URL from `@ionic-native/camera`, however I cannot find where it's now since version changed.

Without it I get url like (looks good, but does not work):

[image]

Code:

```
getImage() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 600, 
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => { 
        this.imageURI = imageData;
        // this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);
        alert(this.imageURI);
        alert(imageData);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Already tried `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`, but no result. Unfortunately I cannot debug my code via Chrome or emulator for several reasons. Maybe `normalizeUrl` can help me but it's not in the @ionic/angular package.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was this code 
After imports and before component insert
`declare var window;`
then

```
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then(
      imageData => { 
        this.imageURI = window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc(imageData)
        // this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);
        alert(this.imageURI);
        alert(imageData);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    );
```

worked like a charm!

Comment: Replace `window.Ionic` using `this` and the webview. See https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview/